# What does the letter A mean at the first frame of revolution slider?

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

What does the letter A mean at the first frame of revolution slider?

I mean I Duplicated a text layer, but The duplicate layer does not have the letter A in the beginning, How Can I add that?

Photo:
[image: Photo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That mean: a text layer waiting for an action by another layer or button.

you can set from [layer option => action tab => target layer] for that button or layer

Answer (score 0):

Normally the letter `a` is used to identify something related to text. However considering Revolution slider has animations it is possible that that layer has animations applied. Try to right click on it and inspect the code. See what kind of classes it has and names, or perhaps it has a tool-tip hover.

Comment: Hi, I couldn't find that by classes